# What is the least invasive thing I can install to get Node-gyp to run?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, node.js

I'm trying to host https://github.com/spark/spark-server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box.

I installed git, node and python. When I get to the `npm install` step, I get the following message:

> MSBUILD : error MBS3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component
>   "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2)
>   install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the
>   component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere. 
>   [C:\nodejs\spark-server\js\mode_modules\ursa\build\binding.sln]

This isn't a dev box and I really don't want to install either. But if I do, I'd rather not install outdated SDKs and IDEs. What is the recommended way to deal with this?

EDIT: Found the answer. Install:

- [Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop)
- [Latest 64-bit version of OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

  - Full version, not the light version
  - Install to `C:\OpenSSL-Win64` (this is hardcoded in the ursa package)
  - May need to first install the VC++ 2008 runtime from the link in the OpenSSL list; the installer will tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Some node packages incorporate native code and therefore must be compiled for the target system, so you need to have a compiler installed.

The free version of [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8) (*not* for Web) should be sufficient.

Once installed, run your installation within the Visual Studio Command Prompt (x64), and with a slight modification:

```
npm install --msvs_version=2013
```

The real path of least resistance, of course, is to deploy to a Linux server. While the same is true of Linux, that you usually need a compiler, many distributions provide precompiled packages for the more popular software.

Comment: For Windows or for Windows Desktop?

Comment: For Windows (not Windows Desktop, not Web, not anything else). The link should have taken you directly to it, but it won't work with JavaScript disabled (haha).

Comment: There is no "Visual Studio Command Prompt." There is a "VS2012 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt." But then I have to specify `--msvs_version=2012`.
And then a build error C1083: Cannot open include file `winsock2.h`. Are you sure I shouldn't have gotten the Windows Desktop version?

Comment: Hm. Despite its unfortunate name, I think you're looking for [VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XhdtM.png).

Comment: Followed your link, downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 with Update 4 for Windows - English.

Comment: Exact same outcome. Need winsock2.h.

Comment: Hm. I think [this github issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/339) might be relevant here. Looks like there is a workaround available. You want to try Linux instead? I promise it will be easier! :)

Comment: I was right, the guys in the thread used the Windows Desktop version. If you correct your answer I'll mark it. Now it looks like all I need is the OpenSSL include files and I'm good to go.